# Нужны универсальные функции INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE и DELETE!

Tags: php, функции, mysqli

Не могли бы вы помочь новичку?! 
В общем есть База Данных. В Денвере. (хотя БД не имеет значения) 
Есть базы CARS, FOOTBALL и COUNTRIES. 
Внутри баз все одинаковое!
К примеру: в CARS главная таблица МАРКИ (Мерс, БМВ, Ауди и т.д.)
А потом идет таблица МОДЕЛИ, которые привязаны к МАРКАМ (к примеру МЕРС - Gelandewagen, SLK и CLK).
В FOOTBALL - главная КЛУБЫ, а вторая - ИГРОКИ в них. 
В COUNTRIES - главная СТРАНЫ, а ВТОРАЯ - ГОРОДА в них.

Суть вопроса: дело в том что у меня много разных запросов из "process.php" в "functions.php", для таких функций как INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE и DELETE:

```
function insert_add_marka($connect){

    $marka=@$_POST['marka_name'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM marki WHERE marka_name='$marka'";

    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    $get=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    if($get['id']==0){  
        $sql="INSERT INTO marki (marka_name)value('$marka')";
        $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>"; 
    }
}

function update_edit_marka($connect){

    $marka=@$_POST['marka_name'];
    $marka_id=@$_POST['marka_id'];

    $sql="UPDATE marki SET marka_name='$marka' WHERE id=$marka_id";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";    
}

function insert_add_model($connect){

    $file_name=null;
    $file_error=@$_FILES['photo_file']['error'];

    if($file_error==0){
        $file_name=@$_FILES['photo_file']['name'];
        $file_tmp_name=@$_FILES['photo_file']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_file']['tmp_name'], "../uploads/". $_FILES['photo_file']['name']);
    }

    $mod_name=@$_POST['model_name'];
    $opisanie=@$_POST['opisanie'];
    $marka_id=@$_POST['marka_id'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM car_models WHERE model_name='$mod_name'";

    $res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    $get=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    if($get['id']==0){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO car_models (model_name, photo, opisanie, marka_id)values('$mod_name','$file_name','$opisanie', $marka_id)";
        $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        echo "<script>window.location='model.php?marka_id=$marka_id'</script>";
    }
}
```

Теперь преподаватель хочет чтобы у меня были новые универсальные функции Insert, select, update и delete для всех случаев жизни!

Но как это сделать, если к примеру в `$sql="INSERT INTO marki (marka_name)value('$marka')"` приходят 3 параметра, а в 
`$sql = "INSERT INTO car_models (model_name, photo, opisanie, marka_id)values('$mod_name','$file_name','$opisanie', $marka_id)"` - уже 9 параметров!

В `$sql="UPDATE marki SET marka_name='$marka' WHERE id=$marka_id";` - 4 параметра приходят, а в 
 `$sql = "UPDATE car_models SET model_name='$mod_name', photo='$file_name', marka_id='$marka_id', opisanie='$opisanie' WHERE id=$model_id";` - 9-10 параметров!

Уже 4 день пишу код - не получается! И в интернете такого найти не могу!

Кто-нибудь уже сталкивался - и писал такие универсальные функции `INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE и DELETE`?!

ВНИМАНИЕ: Классы я еще не использую! Просьба писать ответы без них!

Заранее спасибо за подзатыльник в нужном направлении! :-)

Comment: Передавать в функции не отдельные параметры, а массивы. А внутри уже делать `explode(',', $arr)` или по вкусу

Comment: А можно пример? Как это будет выглядить?

Answer (score 1):

В реальном проекте так делать ни в коем случае нельзя, но для "пинка в нужную сторону" самое оно:

```
$car_models_values = array(
  'model_id'   => '1',
  'model_name' => 'Name1',
  'photo'      => 'photo.png',
  'opisanie'   => 'bla-bla-bla',
);

insert('car_models', $car_models_values);

function insert($table, $data) {
  $columns = "'" . implode("','", array_keys($data)) . "'";
  $values = "'" . implode("','", array_values($data)) . "'";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$columns}) VALUES ({$values})";
  ...
}
```

Comment: Но здесь у меня возникает другой вопрос:

Как быть если у меня есть два вида SELECT?

В одном у меня просто перебирается массив, а второй после переборки используется для вывода результата в таблицу!

Comment: 1) function select2($hren1, $hren2, $connect){  [B]//  здесь  перебирается массив.[/B]
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $hren1 WHERE id=$hren2";
//echo $sql;
$hren3 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$hren4=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hren3); 
return $hren4;

2) function select4($hren1, $hren2, $hren3, $connect){  [B]// здесь после перебирания массива - идет цикл в таблице[/B]
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $hren1 WHERE $hren2=$hren3";

 $hren4 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

 $hren5=array();

 $i=0;

 while ($hren6=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hren4)){
  
  $hren5[$i]=$hren6;
  $i++;
 }
 return $hren5;
}

Comment: Спасибо @toxxxa! <br> А как сделать функцию UPDATE для массива?<br>

$sql = "UPDATE car_models SET model_name='$mod_name', marka_id='$marka_id', opisanie='$opisanie' WHERE id=$model_id";